# A sequence converging to 0 in probability times a sequence bounded in probability

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, random-variables

I'm trying to prove the following from Lehman's "Elements of Large Sample Theory"

> **Lemma 2.3.1**: If the sequence $\{Y_n, n=1,2,\ldots\}$ is bounded in probability and if $\{C_n\}$ is a sequence of random variables tending to $0$ in probability, then $C_n Y_n \xrightarrow{P} 0 $

(The notation "$\xrightarrow{P}$" indicates convergence in probability.)

Here was my initial attack: We know that for any epsilon, sufficiently large $n$ and suitable $K$ that (1) $$P\left(| Y_n | \leq K\right) > 1 - \epsilon_0$$

Similarly, we know that for any $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 > 0$, sufficiently large $n$ that (2)

$$
P\left(|C_n| < \frac{\epsilon_1}{K}\right) > 1 - \epsilon_2
$$

Here's where I run into trouble. If **we assume independence of the two sequences**, we should be able to multiply the probabilities (1) and (2) above to get:

$$
P(|Y_n C_n| < \epsilon_1) > (1-\epsilon_0) (1-\epsilon_2) \to 1
$$

Since the choices of epsilons were arbitrary.

My problem is that **what if we can't assume independence**? So this proof strikes me as incorrect but probably my heart is in the right place. Any help is much appreciated. I'll think about it myself and make edits if I make any progress.

UPDATE 1:

I'm beginning to think that instead of considering $P((1) \land (2))$, we should perhaps consider$\overline {P((1) \land (2))}$, since $\overline {P((1) \land (2))} < P(\overline{(1)}) + P(\overline{(2)}$. Now we should be able to show $ P(\overline{(1)}) + P(\overline{(2)} \to 0$, without assuming anything about independence.

Comment: The Update puts you on the right course.

Comment: I'd change the $<$ in the update to $\leq$, but other than that it looks fine.